# Java.lang.StackOverflowError in sony devices

Tags: android, stack-overflow, pull-to-refresh

Now am facing a strange issue,in my list view i am using pull to refresh list it is working fine in Samsung Galaxy s2,but when i  tested the same app in sony devices it is crashing when  i pull  to refresh the list,it shows java.lang.StackOverflowError.please check the error log and give me a solution.

```
04-27 17:46:23.874: W/dalvikvm(8663): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b547210)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): java.lang.StackOverflowError
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawTextRun(GLES20Canvas.java:1100)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawTextRun(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:295)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.text.TextLine.drawTextRun(TextLine.java:1067)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:791)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:1034)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.text.TextLine.drawRun(TextLine.java:397)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.text.TextLine.draw(TextLine.java:195)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.text.BoringLayout.drawInternal(BoringLayout.java:1019)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:950)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5067)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11082)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10521)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10519)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10519)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10519)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10519)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.widget.ListView.drawChild(ListView.java:3219)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2099)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3214)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11085)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3419)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at com.technoracle.chattrspace_demo_refresh.PullToRefreshView$InternalListView.draw(PullToRefreshView.java:59)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10521)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10519)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11085)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10521)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10519)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10519)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10519)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10519)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10519)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10519)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10519)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10519)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10519)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2954)
04-27 17:46:23.894: E/AndroidRuntime(8663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you definitely have recursive-calling functions `getDisplayList()`, `drawChild()` and `dispatchDraw()` that overflow your stack no matter what. you may check the contents of these functions and see how to break the recursive calling pattern, so they eventually return back.

maybe there's something wrong with your layout where elements depend on each other or something like that.

Comment: thanks for the response.issue is in my layout.it is working now